# How to Fix Data Push Issues in Next.js 13 with Prisma

Tags: reactjs, forms, next.js, prisma

Guys can you please check what is wrong with my code? My data is not pushing to my database, I'm using Supabase for database, NextJs 13 and Prisma:

```
>   const submitData = async (e: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
>     e.preventDefault();
>     try {
>       const body = {
>         positionCode,
>         positionName,
>       };
>       await fetch("../api/post", {
>         method: "POST",
>         headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
>         body: JSON.stringify(body),
>       });
>       const form = e.target as HTMLFormElement;
>       // This line submits the form
>       form.submit();
>       window.location.reload();
>     } catch (error) {
>       console.error(error);
>     }   };
```

and here is the code for my post:

```
> import prisma from "../../../lib/prisma";
> 
> export default async function handle(req: any, res: any) {   const {
>     positionCode,
>     positionName,
>     positionType,
>     positionRank,
>     positionDescription,
>     positionDuties,   } = req.body;   console.log(req.body);
> 
>   try {
>     const position = await prisma.position.create({
>       data: {
>         positionCode,
>         positionName,
>       },
>     });
> 
>     res.json(position);   } catch (error) {
>     res.status(400).json({ error });   } }
```

Comment: Do you get any specific errors?